# CMake GUI - Adding XCode Generator

Tags: xcode, cmake, generator

I've downloaded CMake GUI 2.8-4, launched it, but the only generator I see is "Unix MakeFile".
How may I set XCode as the current generator ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete your build tree, (or even just CMakeCache.txt) and start over. When you first configure a build tree, you have to choose a generator. After that, the generator value is cached in CMakeCache.txt and used on all subsequent configures.

The only way to change it is to start with a clean build tree.